# HTMLEditFormat Syntax Issues - XSS

Tags: coldfusion, xss

I'm attempting to work on some possible XSS flaws in my code and have ran into some issues.

This code doesn’t work (line 297) - Syntax error:

```
#iif(HTMLEditFormat (not url.excludeFinalized),de(" disabled"),de("")) )#
```

This code does work (line 298):

```
#iif(HTMLEditFormat(url.excludeFinalized),de(" checked"),de("")) )#
```

This ‘not’ is what's messing me up - How would I properly place HTMLEditFormat into the code above or below?

```
#iif(not subgroupExercisesDone and nodeIsRollup,de("disabled"),de(""))#
```

Thanks for any help. I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: If you CF version is high enough, a ternary operator is available that might simplify matters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this change:

```
#iif((not url.excludeFinalized),de(HTMLEditFormat(" disabled")),de("")) )#
```

Your original code wraps HTMLEditFormat around a condition.  And there's no need to HEF() and empty string, so you still have just one usage of HTMLEditFormat.  I don't think you need HTMLEditFormat at all, to be honest.

I think.  Didn't test this myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the `NOT` inside the function call like that.

This is more in line with what you were trying to do.

```
#iif(NOT HTMLEditFormat(url.excludeFinalized),de(" disabled"),de("")))#
```

But if `HTMLEditFormat(url.excludeFinalized)` can't be resolved as a Boolean value, you're going to get a runtime error.